# Visual Composer Tabs don't work on mobile

Tags: plugins

http://loft.qodeweb.com/njegoseva/karta-pica/

Hi, I am trying to figure out why tabs do not work on mobile and tablet. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( function($) {
jQuery('.vc_tta-tab a').on('click', function( e ){
setTimeout( function() { 
jQuery('html, body').stop().stop();
console.log('scrolling stopped');
}, 100 );
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.vc_tta.vc_general .vc_tta-panel-title > a, .vc_tta.vc_general .vc_tta-panel-title > a, .vc_tta-tab a').off('click touchstart touchend');
});
});
```

This is the code that works.